# module.export not exporting the file, to be imported in main.js

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am using Visual code as an IDE to work on Javascript.

I am going through some tutorials and I encountered an issue which I am failing in solving it

I am using module.export to export my js file, and I am using require to use it in my main file. However, It is not working, as I am expecting an alert message to pop up.

Following is my code

```
    **task.js**
    /* jshint node: true */
    'use strict';
    class Task {

            constructor(name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            completed() {
                alert(this.name);
            }
     }
     module.export = Task;

     **cat.js**
    /* jshint node: true */
    'use strict';
    function Cat(name) {
        this.name = name;

        this.toString = function() {
                alert(name);
        };
    }

    Cat.prototype.complete = function() {
        console.log('Completed');
    };
    module.export = Cat;

    **main.js**
    var Task = require('./task');
    var Cat = require('./cat');
    // Ways to create instances.

    var task1 = new Task("A");

    task1.completed();


    var cat1 = new Cat("Fluffy");
    cat1.toString();
    cat1.complete();

  **Demo1.html**
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
        <h1> Hello! </h1>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Directory structure:

```
.vscode
   script
     cat.js
     task.js
     main.js
demo1.html
```

I am not getting errors on the output console. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which module bundler are you using?

Comment: I am not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: You would know because you would have to set it up. Unless vscode does this magically for you (don't know). Generally speaking, browsers don't support the CommonJS module system used by Node, so unless something is bundling the modules one way or the other, this won't work (and you should see an error).

Comment: VsCode did it for me. I did not install any module bundler. I googled and read that vscode uses Rollup. I ran the same code on cloud9 and it worked now. It has something to do with the way vscode is setup. I really hope I knew how all the pieces fit together. Right now, it feels like I am solving a part of a puzzle. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have a typo! Use `module.exports` instead of `module.export`.

[Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)

If you are interested in the future of javascript, you can take a look at `export`([Export Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)) which has slightly different syntax. It is not yet supported by most browsers so a transpiler would be needed for using it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that. However, that did not fix it still. I really hoped that would fix the issue.

Comment: I will try going through the documentation and see if I can fix this. Thanks

Comment: It worked on Cloud9, so I am not sure what was wrong. This made me realize I need to understand the entire setup of JS and not just the coding part. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: No problem. If this solved your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to the question.